# Need to make a link responsive with the rest of my <div>

Tags: html, css, angular

How do I group the viewtransactions with the myLink. I want the link to follow the text. What I have now works for desktop but as soon as I switch it to a smaller viewport the link is out of position. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class= "footer">
    <p [innerHTML]="viewTransactions | fdContent"></p>
     &nbsp;
    <a [attr.href]="myLink" [innerHTML]="statementsLbl | fdContent"></a>
</div>

.footer {
display: flex;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS:

```
.footer {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
}
```

It should work to all screen sizes
and this is a live demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vy2puw?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: That centers it on desktop view too which is not needed. Still out of place in small viewport as well. Do i need something like a @Media query?

Comment: @rdopler can you please accept the answer if it worked for you ?